# Resetting line count in dtx files

Tags: line-numbering, dtx

I'm writing a `dtx` file containing several source files. Is there a way to reset the line counter when commenting the code of a different file?

My `dtx` file looks something like this:

```
....
%\iffalse
%<file1>
%\fi
% .... comments and code of file 1
%\iffalse
%</file1>
%<file2>
%\fi
% .... comments and code of file 2 ... etc.
```

and I would like the line numbers of the code of file2 to start with 1 again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc package uses the `CodelineNo` counter so `\setcounter{CodelineNo}{0}` probably does what you need.